# Power BI: Usar Medidas como Filtro

Tags: powerbi, dax

Tenho um dashboard com uma tabela que mostra a contagem de linhas em uma tabela de banco de dados, de acordo com seus códigos.

Eu dividi em Medidas, vários **CALCULATE(s)** se a linha na tabela conter um código especifico.
Por exemplo, se for igual a 1, ele conta a linha (ou o id nesse caso):

```
medida1 = CALCULATE(COUNT(tabela[id]),tabela[codigo]=1)
```

Eu fiz **5 medidas** com códigos específicos para que seja mostrado na tabela corretamente como colunas.
 Reforço que no código real, nas medidas, teria dois códigos a serem comparados e cheio de condições lógicas com **"&" e "||"**.

Só que agora, eu tenho uma ideia para uma nova medida para mostrar a quantia de todas as linhas, exceto as das 5 medidas previamente criadas.
Como posso usar essas medidas como filtro? Ou, tem algum outro jeito de resolver meu problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem como utilizar medidas previamente criadas como filtro, pois o resultado de uma medida é um número ou "string" e não a lógica como o resultado foi calculado.

Para utilizar, por exemplo, duas medidas numa nova medida:

```
medida1 = CALCULATE(COUNT(tabela[id]),tabela[codigo]=1)
medida2 = CALCULATE(COUNT(tabela[id]),tabela[codigo]=2)
```

É preciso negar a lógica das medidas numa nova medida, utilizando o [NOT](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dax/not-function-dax) do DAX.

```
medida3 = CALCULATE(COUNT(tabela[id]), NOT(tabela[codigo] = 1), NOT(tabela[codigo] = 2))
```

Fonte: [Power BI: Using Measures as filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71972522/power-bi-using-measures-as-filter/71979132#71979132)